# 音声認識APIを使用したアプリに関しての質問

Tags: java, api, google-cloud

プログラミング初心者です。

現在、Google Cloud Speech APIをしようしたアプリを作ろうとしています。

このAPIを使用して、ユーザーが発音した単語を結果として表示します。
その際に、複数の候補がある場合（例えば、ユーザーが「save」と発音した際、発音が悪く、「save」か「shave」なのかわからない）、saveとshaveの両方を結果として表示したいです。

例えば、google translateでは、saveかshaveのどちらか一方が表示されます。
しかし、「発音チェック」というアプリでは（googleのAPI（たぶんspeech API）を使用）、発音が悪いと、saveとshaveの両方が表示されます。

私は、発音チェックと同様の結果を表示したいです。

どのようにすれば、発音チェックのように複数候補を結果として返すことができますか？

Answer (score 0):

ご質問の「Google Cloud Speech API」と同じものかどうか分かりませんが、以下のページに概要が記述されていますので、参照してみてください。

[Cloud Speech-to-Text の基本](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics?hl=ja)

> 音声同期認識リクエスト
>
> `maxAlternatives` - （オプション、デフォルト`1`）レスポンスで表示する音声文字変換候補の数を示します。デフォルトでは、Speech-to-Text API は最も可能性が高い音声文字変換候補を 1 つ表示します。別の変換候補も表示するには、`maxAlternatives`を 1 よりも大きな値に設定します。Speech-to-Text は、品質が十分であると判断された変換候補のみ返します。変換候補の表示は一般に、ユーザー フィードバックを必要とするリアルタイムのリクエスト（音声コマンドなど）に適しているため、ストリーミング認識リクエスト向けです。
>
> Speech-to-Text API レスポンス
>
> `alternatives`には`SpeechRecognitionAlternatives`型の音声文字変換テキスト候補のリストが格納されます。複数の変換候補が表示されるかどうかは、ユーザーが（maxAlternatives に`1`より大きい値に設定して）複数の変換候補をリクエストしたかどうか、さらに Speech-to-Text が十分に高品質の変換候補を生成したかどうかによって異なります。各変換候補は次のフィールドから構成されます。
>
> - `transcript`には音声文字変換テキストが含まれます。後述の音声文字変換テキストの処理をご覧ください。
> - `confidence`には、Speech-to-Text の特定の音声文字変換テキストの信頼度を示す 0 から 1 までの値が格納されます。後述の信頼値の解釈をご覧ください。
>
> 変換候補（alternatives）の選択
>
> 正常な同期認識レスポンス内の各結果に、1 つまたは複数（リクエストの`maxAlternatives`値が`1`より大きい場合）の`alternatives`が含まれる場合があります。Speech-to-Text で、変換候補の信頼値が十分に高いと判断された場合、その変換候補はレスポンスに含められます。レスポンスの最初の変換候補が、通常は最適な（最も可能性が高い）変換候補です。
>
> `maxAlternatives`を`1`より大きい値に設定しても、複数の変換候補が返されるとは限りません。一般に、複数の変換候補は、ストリーミング認識リクエストによって結果を取得するユーザーにリアルタイムのオプションを提供する場合に適しています。

---

> 非同期リクエストとレスポンス
>
> LongRunningRecognize メソッドに対する非同期 Speech-to-Text API リクエストの形式は、同期 Speech-to-Text API リクエストと同じです。
>
> 次にリクエストの完了後のすべてのレスポンスを示します。～途中省略～この型は、同期 Speech-to-Text API 認識リクエストによって返される型と同じです。

---

> ストリーミング Speech-to-Text API 認証リクエスト
>
> `config` - （必須）RecognitionConfig 型の音声の構成情報が含まれます。これは同期リクエストや非同期リクエストで指定するものと同じです。
>
> ストリーミング レスポンス
>
> `alternatives`には候補の音声文字変換リストが含まれます。